# Climber badge?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Just an idea on a fun badge...
Say a user gain lots of reputation in short period of time (to be determine (X amount of points and Y amount of time).... he is a climber or rising star, etc. etc.  Pick your wording.

Comment: Seems to me like the badge in general is a bit vague. Power users already in the top hundred are very likely to get this but aren't really 'climbing' up in the community, they're already established. Getting max rep seems like a good reward on its own to me.

Comment: How is this proposal different from the already-implemented badges for hitting daily rep limits? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7020/award-badge-for-hitting-daily-rep-limit

Comment: I like this badge as long is it is represented by the Price is Right Mountain Climber.

Comment: I think this is different from the daily rep limit badges... but... do we really need *more* badges for this?

Comment: Cody's right - the badges implemented in response to that other question (asked 5 months later than this one) address the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

X consecutive days of >= 190 daily rep?  The **"[yellow jersey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_jersey)"** badge, perhaps?

Filburt makes an excellent alternative suggestion: [the dotted jersey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountains_classification_in_the_Tour_de_France) (for mastery of climbing mountains).

Comment: Cool idea, but I'd put it at 190 or 195 rep just so a late downvote doesn't mess with the streak.

Comment: Yellow Jersey? Is it there? I don't know if one exists.

Comment: A bronze badge for hitting it once, silver for 5 consecutive days, and gold for how many days?

Comment: @pgs: gold for 365 consecutive days ;-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be the [dotted jersey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountains_classification_in_the_Tour_de_France)?

Comment: I've edited per Filburt and Kyle's suggestions - thanks to both

Answer (score 6):

I like this idea. Call it "Ascender," "Rising Star" (as suggested), or something else entirely. I'd put two conditions on it, though:

1. User has 5 consecutive days (I say 5 for those that take weekends off) of 190 rep gain (kudos to Kyle for catching the downvote issue)
2. User has < 5000 rep (otherwise you'll hit the issue where folks with high reps and lots of posts get this badge every day).

Comment: There's the condition I was looking for. Also, the ability to earn only once might be nice.

Comment: If you want to exclude the weekend just average it out to be 1000 rep/week? Since the rep is capped, it doesn't matter if a couple of days were a little lower (it's still a lot!)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a points based badge why not have a badge for the biggest mover of the day in terms of moving up the users list.

Or how bout having the badge based on an equation which takes into account the amount of upvotes compared to how many times the question has been viewed (so that its not just the c# answers that get the badges). Lets give a little consideration to the less popular questions.

Comment: I like this idea a lot. It would be hard to grant to a single users because with caps many users could finish with the same rep, however something like 'Top User of the Day' for each day. Whoever gained the most gross rep for a day could get the badge, and use them like Trophies. "I have been top user 3 times, X has been top user 5 times".

Comment: Anything along the several points you suggest could be neat.