# Award badge for hitting daily rep limit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, badges

A badge could be awarded to users who have received enough votes on a given day to trigger the 200 reputation/day limit. This would let them know that they've hit the limit, and the badge would be excellent compensation for any rep that is eaten by the rep limit beast.

Edit: This should probably be a once only badge, awarded the first time a user hits the rep limit.

Comment: Similar enough to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5448/climber-badge to make this question redundant.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7060/badge-for-upvotes-after-rep-cap-is-reached

Comment: Add it to the main list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Implemented:

> [Mortarboard] - hit rep cap once
>   [Epic] - hit rep cap 50 times
>   [Legendary] - hit rep cap 150 times

All are single-award badges.

Comment: +1 for free surprise badges :)

Answer (score 13):

That's a nice idea. But it should be given only for the first time. Because then people like Jon Skeet would get one of those per day...

EDIT: Not sure if it better be bronze or silver, though.

Comment: +1 It should also be bronze at best.

Comment: I am not sure about bronze: "Bronze badges are earned for basic use of the Stack Overflow site; they are relatively easy to earn.". "Silver badges are earned for longer term goals. Silver badges are uncommon, but definitely attainable if you’re interested enough."

Comment: I don't think hitting the rep cap counts as basic use.

Comment: Hitting rep count isn't really that difficult. If it can be earned more than once it *has* to be bronze or it would just be pollution, and even at bronze would create almost 100+ more badges for long time users.

Comment: @Ian: yeah, you're right. I've been thinking, and everytime I hit the rep limit I did it with two or three answers. Bronze it is.

Comment: If it was multiple Jon Skeet would get this 250-300 times to start probably. Hell I'm sure I'd get it 150+ times.

Comment: Seems strange to make it bronze when "Teacher", the badge for getting your first upvote on a question at all, is a bronze badge.

Comment: Looking at Martinho's first comment, it's not really either bronze or silver.  It's definitely beyond "basic" use, but it's not a long-term goal either.  My vote is silver, but only awarded once.

Comment: My vote is for silver, because users, such as myself, who don't ask a lot of questions or give a lot of answers will probably never get it.

Answer (score 8):

It should be for hitting like 245 in a day.  You would have to get a bounty or at least 3 correct answers after you have hit 200.  That would make it a challenge.

Comment: And make it GOLD!

Comment: Bounties make that much more possible. I've gained 750+ in a day (200 daily cap, 500 bounty, can't remember if I had any accepted answers after that).

Comment: Definitely not gold. Possibly bronze for 275, silver for 350, gold for 500. Only award each badge once.

Comment: Some regression analysis would need to be done on the DB to find out exactly what scores should award what level of badge.  Where is Sam when you need him? :)

Comment: Love Jon Skeet's answer... 500 for Gold would be a real challenge, but I don't really like the idea that all three could be awarded by just getting one bounty (all be it rare and high).

Comment: 275 for bronze?  For "basic use of the stack overflow site"?  Equivalent in level to "Teacher", the bronze badge for getting your first upvote on an answer?

Comment: I like Jon skeet's idea, but the bronze level should just be for exceeding the cap, ie > 200 with emphasis on the >.

Comment: How is getting >200 points in a day "basic use"?  It means you got a lot of upvotes, relatively few downvotes, and at least one accepted answer, all on the same day.  I've got ~4k on SO, and I've never managed it, despite having one answer with more than 40 votes (over a longer period of time).  Granted, I haven't gone crazy trying to earn rep...but I defintely qualify in most respects as having used SO in at least a "basic" way.  I think hitting 200 without having gone over is definitely good enough for a bronze.  (And no, I still wouldn't qualify, so I'm not aruging for that sake.)

Comment: @JP: ...unless you've downvoted someone today, in which case you'd still not get it. :(

Answer (score 7):

Have three versions of it, similar to the badges you can get when you are voted up a certain number of times for answers to questions of a given tag:

- 1st hit: bronze
- 100th hit: silver
- 500th hit: gold

Comment: 500th may be a bit extreme. Not even Jon Skeet has done that (unless he used his super powers to hit the cap on days that don't yet exist).

Comment: 1st time: silver, 50th or 100th time gold would be a bit more realistic.

Answer (score 5):

1. If this is something you are proposing gets awarded every time you hit rep limit I wholeheartedly disagree. For many of us, that means we will start getting a badge every single day, and eventually we're going to have so many badges that they start to lose what little value each one actually had.
2. If this is something that only gets awarded the first time you hit rep limit (or perhaps after hitting the rep limit X times), then I could agree with that moreso.

Answer (score 2):

I just came to meta to propose this badge.  I agree with those who want it to be a one-time, bronze badge.

Hitting the rep limit the first time should be celebrated!